# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I don't understand the reason why I'm getting such an error in my new project, mvn spring-boot:run I get this error when I execute the command

ERROR:    **Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring5webapp: An exception occurred while running. null**

**pom.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring5webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring5webapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>


    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole output and the command you are executing(maybe with -v)?

Comment: "mvn sprin-boot:run"  I get this error when I execute the command @dan1st

Comment: You may need to add dependencies...

Comment: I'm a little new, can you explain @dan1st

Comment: You've created a spring boot project but it has no dependencies. In other words it doesn't use the spring libraries. If you e.g. want to create a web project, you'll need the web dependency.

Comment: I think you need the `org.springframework.boot` dependency in anycase.

Comment: Can you post your project on Github?

Comment: Maybe a silly question but are you running `mvn package` before you try to run the application?

Comment: Also, I think you need to add the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE:repackage` plugin goal in your `plugins` element.

Comment: https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring5webapp/tree/equals @EugenCovaci

Answer (score 1):

I tried with your pom.xml and it worked for me. It fails with same error only when you have same port (8080 or whatever you are using in the application) has already been occupied.

Can you please check the availability  of the port on which you are trying to run.(if its occupied try running on other port or kill the same).

Also can you please paste the complete error after "null" in the stacktrace.